# Clicking through images next/previous

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
<div class="post-378 page type-page status-publish hentry" id="post-378">
    <ul id='gallery_square_grid'>
        <li>
            <a data-caption='This is the caption text' class='gallery_square' href='image/2016/08/fpo_blue.png'>
                <span class='title'>fpo_blue</span>
                <img src='image/2016/08/fpo_blue-120x120.png' alt='Description' />
                <br />
                <span class='description'>Description</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-caption='This is the caption text' class='gallery_square' href='image/2016/08/fpo_orange.png'>
                <span class='title'>fpo_orange</span>
                <img src='image/2016/08/fpo_orange-120x120.png' alt='Description' />
                <br />
                <span class='description'>Description</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-caption='This is the caption text' class='gallery_square' href='image/2016/08/fpo_moss.png'>
                <span class='title'>fpo_moss</span>
                <img src='image/2016/08/fpo_moss-120x120.png' alt='Description' />
                <br />
                <span class='description'>Description</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-caption='This is the caption text' class='gallery_square' href='image/2016/08/fpo_midnight.png'>
                <span class='title'>fpo_midnight</span>
                <img src='image/2016/08/fpo_midnight-120x120.png' alt='Description' />
                <br />
                <span class='description'>Description</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-caption='This is the caption text' class='gallery_square' href='image/2016/08/fpo_magenta.png'>
                <span class='title'>fpo_magenta</span>
                <img src='image/2016/08/fpo_magenta-120x120.png' alt='Description' />
                <br />
                <span class='description'>Description</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-caption='This is the caption text' class='gallery_square' href='image/2016/08/fpo_lime.png'>
                <span class='title'>fpo_lime</span>
                <img src='image/2016/08/fpo_lime-120x120.png' alt='Description' />
                <br />
                <span class='description'>Description</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-caption='This is the caption text' class='gallery_square' href='image/2016/08/fpo_lavander.png'>
                <span class='title'>fpo_lavander</span>
                <img src='image/2016/08/fpo_lavander-120x120.png' alt='Description' />
                <br />
                <span class='description'>Description</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-caption='This is the caption text' class='gallery_square' href='image/2016/08/fpo_dusty_pink.png'>
                <span class='title'>fpo_dusty_pink</span>
                <img src='image/2016/08/fpo_dusty_pink-120x120.png' alt='Description' />
                <br />
                <span class='description'>Description</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-caption='This is the caption text' class='gallery_square' href='image/2016/08/fpo_cherry.png'>
                <span class='title'>fpo_cherry</span>
                <img src='image/2016/08/fpo_cherry-120x120.png' alt='Description' />
                <br />
                <span class='description'>Description</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-caption='This is the caption text' class='gallery_square' href='image/2016/08/fpo_brown.png'>
                <span class='title'>fpo_brown</span>
                <img src='image/2016/08/fpo_brown-120x120.png' alt='Description' />
                <br />
                <span class='description'>Description</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I would like to use Jquery or JS to be able to allow a user to click a next and previous button to click through these images fullscreen.  I have the code that allows the image to pop up once clicked: http://jonsymond.com/alp/gallery/

Comment: can you add the JS as well

Comment: What does "click through" mean? Are you talking about setting up a slide show controlled via the Previous & Next buttons? Is the plan to "click through" the images referred to in your anchor elements' `href` attributes, or through the existing img elements?

Comment: I would like a next and previous button, to be able to click through the images when they popup fullscreen, so there would be a next and previous button for fullscreen images.

Comment: If an image is "fullscreen" then there is no room for buttons.

Comment: the button would be at the bottom, enough room to show them.  The important thing is just the next and previous of the images which I have spent all day and can't get.